# Use of would with type 1 conditionals

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

This is regarding the use of 'would' inside type 1 conditional.

From:  [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/How-to-Use-Could-Would-and-Should): *How to Use "Could," "Would," and "Should"*

> Example 1: *If we invite him, Adam would visit us on Monday.* (If we
> choose to invite him over, we predict that Adam will accept our
> invitation and come over.)

- Example 2: *If it stops raining, we would go for a picnic.*

Some other sources say “would” cannot be used with the first conditional, which deals with predictions of likely and possible future events. In conditional statements, “would” only deals with the unlikely and the impossible. What would be your take on this?
Grammarly gives an error when I use 'would' in the above two cases.

Comment: They don't feel idiomatic to me. _If it stops raining, we will go for a picnic_ or _If it stopped raining, we would go for a picnic_.

Comment: I have to say the first example doesn't seem idiomatic to me either.  Perhaps if there was some additional context where Adam had previously mentioned his willingness to visit, it might be possible to use this construction, but this is very specific.  I can't really think of context for the second example where this would be possible either. They seem odd, rather than non-grammatical.  Context can fix many issues. Without context, we are just left guessing.

Comment: I hate to argue with Britannica, but as a native speaker, it's not natural, and as an ESL teacher of 19 years, I've never noticed that structure, and I'd expect every teacher I know to mark it wrong. I'm interested in the source material Britannica consulted that convinced them that was correct. Or maybe it's just a typo, and they meant to put "will". They put "will" in the explanation of the meaning, so that's a possibility.

Comment: Apart from Britannica, there is another source that agrees with the usage of 'would' here. It puts the format of the Conditional clause: If + present simple
Main clause: Modal verb with future meaning (shall/should/will/would/can/could/may/might) Source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-if

Answer (score 2):

If the first conditional uses the formula:

if + present simple, ... will + infinitive

then by definition your examples aren't type 1 conditionals, they are some type of hybrid.

> Example 1: If we invite him, Adam would visit us on Monday.

Consider that Adam has free will, and so it's problematic to say about anyone "If we invite person X, they *will* visit us."  "Will" implies a high degree of certainty that you might assign to physical phenomena, or your own intentions, but adding "would" helps to indicate the possible uncertainty of Adam's decisions.   Nevertheless, it's unclear if that exact sentence is correct. It could be expressed in other ways which are less debatable: "If we invite him, Adam will probably come over on Monday."

> Example 2: If it stops raining, we would go for a picnic.

This looks wrong. It should be "If it stops raining, we will go for a picnic."

According to the answer https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316123/how-many-conditional-sentence-types-are-possible/316142#316142 there are two hundred and seventy-seven English conditionals, which means that an assumption of 4 or 5 conditional forms is an oversimplification.

Comment: Don't you think the freewill problem and subsequent error with the usage of "will," can be eliminated with the option of 'might", as in "If we invite him, Adam might visit us on Monday?"

Comment: @brp7 yes "might" is another idea.

Comment: Additionally, I wanted to ask about 'should" usage with unreal (anytime) conditional. Is this usage correct?: If you saw (were to see) him, you should get the money that I lent him. (The intended meaning is "It is unlikely that you see him. But if you do see him, get the money)

Comment: @brp7 , it could be "If you see him, you should", or "If you saw him, you should have" (all in past tense).  The rules of stackexchange are "open another different question".  :-) 
 And, there are many articles online. Search for: english grammar conditionals should

Comment: "If you see him you should get the money' is type 1 (real, real), and "If you saw him, you should have got the money' is a mixed conditional. (if clause unreal anytime, main unreal past)  That is not my question. Why 'should' cannot be used in type 2 conditionals? In the initial example, why not 'should' fit in? The place in the main clause is mostly "would". Anyway, I will write it as a question later at some point.

Comment: The issue of *Adam's free will* is a distraction from the actual question about "would", and can only confuse the OP because it's incorrect. It's trivial to come up with a context where it makes sense, like Adam always accepts our invitations to dinner, so if we invite him for Monday, he'll show up.